# If I use "image=new Image(...)" many times. Will I collect garbage in memory?

Tags: java, image, memory-management, garbage-collection, libgdx

I need to change texture for my "image" many times in my game.

```
 Image image;
 stage1.AddActor(image);
 image = new Image(texture1);
 image = new Image(texture2);
 image = new Image(texture1);
 image = new Image(texture2);
 ...
```

Is it correct? Will I collect garbade in memory or not?
Not comfortable to use a few images such as follows:

```
image1=new Image(texture1);
image2=new Image(texture2);
image1.visible=true;
image2.visible=false;
...
image1.visible=false;
image2.visible=true;
....
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

```
Image image;
image = new Image(texture1);
image = new Image(texture2); //new Image(texture1) can now be GC'ed
```

Note however, that it will be garbage collected only if it is unreachable. So if you have a reference to `new Image(texture1)` in a list for example, it will prevent the garbage collector to do its job.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Image image;
 image = new Image(texture1);
 image = new Image(texture2);
 image = new Image(texture1);
 image = new Image(texture2);
```

Is better approach, because when you do  `image = new Image(texture2);` above instance  `new Image(texture1);` is eligible for GC assuming it is un-reachable.

When GC happens and object will be GCed is JVM responsibility.

Comment: I could not understand the thought. What is GC? I do understand that the first approach is better. Thanks.

Comment: Ah. GC must be Garbadge Collector.But I could not understand the thought concerning "unreachable".

Comment: un-reachable means, direct (or) in-direct references to object.

Comment: ALL IN VAIN. "image = new Image(texture2)" DOES NOT WORK. IMAGE IS THE OLD ON THE SCREEN. OH,LIBGDX! I SHOULD USE SECOND APPROACH ANYWAY.